# Dual Boot broken after Pop!_OS Install

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I've installed a new Linux Distro (Pop!_OS) and it seems like my Windows install is currently unreachable. I've tried many things stated online and nothing seems to be working. Here's the output I see from boot-repair:

> The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to
> fix packages) and reinstall the grub2 of sda3 into the MBRs of all
> disks (except live-disks and removable disks without OS). Grub-efi
> would not be selected by default because: legacy-win no-win-efi
> Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s
> win-legacy-basic-fix
>
> Blockers in case of suggested repair:
>
> ---
>
> LegacyWindows detected. Please enable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy
> mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or
> live-USB). GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB,
> unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via
> tools such as Gparted. Then try again. Alternatively, you can retry
> after activating the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option.

I've tried both of these solutions and still no dice. I'm not fully sure how to enable BIOS compatibility, I have it set to see Legacy and UEFI, but I've tried many different combinations and nothing seems to get a grub screen to show up properly.

Here's my `lsblk` output:

```
➜  ~ lsblk
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda             8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sda1          8:1    0    10M  0 part  <-- this should be the boot partition, but no dice.
├─sda2          8:2    0     4G  0 part  /recovery
├─sda3          8:3    0 457.3G  0 part  /
└─sda4          8:4    0     4G  0 part  
  └─cryptswap 253:0    0     4G  0 crypt [SWAP]
sdb             8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sdb1          8:17   0    16M  0 part  
├─sdb2          8:18   0 465.2G  0 part  
└─sdb3          8:19   0   516M  0 part  
sdc             8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify which distribution and version you installed.

Comment: Updated title and first sentence for you!

Comment: UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. Or once you start to boot you cannot switch modes. You seem to have Windows in legacy/BIOS mode which requires MBR partitioning & Pop!_OS which uses UEFI and should be on a gpt partitioned drive. If totally separate drives, you may be able to boot, but also may have to change to BIOS boot of Windows drive and UEFI boot of Linux drive. If UEFI hardware, best to have all systems installed in UEFI boot mode.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I can’t remember how windows is installed at this point. Sorry for mincing words with BIOS and UEFI.

Comment: You can post link to Summary Report from Boot-Repair if you want more info on how systems are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this solution. By installing os-grober then grub-update via terminal?

```
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt upgrade
> sudo apt install os-prober
```

You well see, that os-prober will detect your Windows 10 partition after typing this,

```
> sudo os-prober
```

Finally, give GRUB command to update the partition data.

```
> sudo update-grub
```

source: [dual-boot-windows-10-pop-os](https://techhut.tv/dual-boot-windows-10-pop-os/)